# Were there any manned missions into orbit that went not to the ISS since the end of the Shuttle?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, soyuz-spacecraft, shenzhou

I know the Chinese did some to their own space station, but were there missions like the repair or retrieve missions the Space Shuttle did with for example the Hubble telescope?

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether or not you count suborbital flights

Comment: Only spaceflights into orbit

Comment: @JamesHughes: Were there any manned suborbital flights? SpaceShipOne flew its last flight while the Shuttle was still operating; AFAIK SpaceShipTwo never crossed 100km; BlueShephard didn't have any manned flights.

Comment: oh, and besides that - the whole China Space Program!

Comment: @SF Ahh, I didn't realise the shuttle was still running when SS1 crashed. I was also planning on checking how high they got if the OP indicated that suborbital flights counted.

Comment: Since the shuttle program shut down there are no manned vehicles capable of repair or retrieval missions. None are on the drawing boards either.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Considering the Shuttle launch would likely cost more than rebuilding and relaunch of any satellite they ever repaired... plus automatics went so far ahead that a robotic repair craft would likely serve the purpose of in-orbit repairs better; cold war is over, and anything that needs to be returned from orbit for scientific value returns on board of Soyuz from ISS.

Comment: @SF raises a good point. The text of your question implies you aren't counting the Chinese space program, so what *are* you asking about? Whether NASA specifically has had manned missions to other destinations?

Comment: I knew about the Chinese program, and wanted to know if there are any manned launches, that went not to the ISS.

Comment: @MrHorse: Well, the simple answer: No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since STS-135, landing 21 July 2011, the only non-ISS flights were three Shenzhou missions (9, 10 and 11), two first to Tiangong 1, third to  Tiangong 2. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_in_spaceflight)

The situation will likely change in upcoming years, with developments of Dragon 2, Starliner, SpaceShipTwo, Blue Shephard, ISRO Orbital Vehicle, and Orion spacecraft on top of sustained China space program and upcoming retirement of ISS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have to wait for more than a few years for Isro's orbital vehicle.

Comment: @neptune: ISRO has pretty good launchers already, and the development began in 2006; the first unmanned [suborbital test launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_Module_Atmospheric_Re-entry_Experiment) was successfully performed in 2014 - it seems if they wanted to rush the program and got the funding, they could have a launch within a year or so; currently the progress depends primarily on funding which is a big unknown, and so the actual manned orbital flight date is hard to estimate, but I don't think "a few years" is overly optimistic.